# Concatenate Series with tuples as index results in multiindex

Tags: pandas, tuples, concatenation

I have two series with tuples as index. The two series have some common index, but not all of them.

When I try to concatenate them (side by side) the resulting dataframe has a multiindex, instead of tuples. How can I have the resulting dataframe to have as index the union of the time series indexes as tuples?

(Note: if the two series have exactly the same tuple indexes, the resulting dataframe has tuples as index as well)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase
from string import ascii_uppercase

ts1 = pd.Series(np.random.rand(5), index = [(ascii_lowercase[ix], ascii_uppercase[ix]) for ix in range(5)])
ts2 = pd.Series(np.random.rand(6), index = [(ascii_lowercase[ix], ascii_uppercase[ix]) for ix in range(6)])

df = pd.concat([ts1, ts2], axis = 1)

ts1
Out[39]: 
(a, A)    0.417022
(b, B)    0.720324
(c, C)    0.000114
(d, D)    0.302333
(e, E)    0.146756

df
Out[38]: 
            0         1
a A  0.417022  0.092339
b B  0.720324  0.186260
c C  0.000114  0.345561
d D  0.302333  0.396767
e E  0.146756  0.538817
f F       NaN  0.419195

df.index
Out[29]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e', u'f', u'g', u'h', u'i', u'j', u'k', u'l', u'm', u'n', u'o', u'p', u'q', u'r', u's', u't'], [u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E', u'F', u'G', u'H', u'I', u'J', u'K', u'L', u'M', u'N', u'O', u'P', u'Q', u'R', u'S', u'T']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the good answers provided so far.
Could you also explain the reason of the behaviour above?
Is it a design choice that makes sense to you or just a shortcoming in the implementation?

Comment: It looks to me that as long as `join=inner` is specified, then regardless of the difference in the length of the 2 series, `concat` knows how to treat their indices (keep their tupleize structure intact). Basically it checks for the intersection of the 2 indices and places them side by side. But when `join=outer` is provided, it starts to flounder on seeing non overlapping indices and as a precautionary step coerces them into separate multi-indices. Mind you, there's no physical difference however on the two `DF's` produced, just that one retains it's structure and the other does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***method 1***
`join`

```
ts1.to_frame('ts1').join(ts2.to_frame('ts2'), how='outer')

             ts1       ts2
(a, A)  0.174646  0.180041
(b, B)  0.674112  0.246414
(c, C)  0.101622  0.142237
(d, D)  0.079782  0.097109
(e, E)  0.613248  0.389077
(f, F)       NaN  0.226176
```

***method 2***
reassign your `index`

```
df = pd.concat([ts1, ts2], axis=1)
df.index = df.index.to_series()
df

               0         1
(a, A)  0.174646  0.180041
(b, B)  0.674112  0.246414
(c, C)  0.101622  0.142237
(d, D)  0.079782  0.097109
(e, E)  0.613248  0.389077
(f, F)       NaN  0.226176
```

***method 3***
`merge`

```
ts1.reset_index().merge(
    ts2.reset_index(), on=['index'], how='outer').set_index('index')

             0_x       0_y
index                     
(a, A)  0.174646  0.180041
(b, B)  0.674112  0.246414
(c, C)  0.101622  0.142237
(d, D)  0.079782  0.097109
(e, E)  0.613248  0.389077
(f, F)       NaN  0.226176
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution is add [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.values.html) for convert `index` to `list` of `tuples`:

```
df = pd.concat([ts1, ts2], axis = 1, keys=['ts1','ts2'])
df.index = df.index.values
print (df)
             ts1       ts2
(a, A)  0.407183  0.866382
(b, B)  0.069167  0.975522
(c, C)  0.697429  0.855803
(d, D)  0.453543  0.011714
(e, E)  0.722056  0.359978
(f, F)       NaN  0.729991
```